# cryption ios crash system stacktrace

Tags: ios, crash, stack-trace

I am receiving crash reports through Crittercism, and I succesfully symbolicate them. But it only contains the call to 'main' and all the rest is cryptic ios stuff which I am unable to decypher. I am not able to reproduce the crash myself.

Can anyone explain me what is going wrong?

```
Thread: Unknown Name (Crashed)

0       libobjc.A.dylib                         0x3194df76 0x3193b000 + 77686

1       Foundation                              0x24a5d2a3 0x248d0000 + 1626787

2       UIKit                                   0x277dfe85 0x27124000 + 7061125

3       UIKit                                   0x277df6c7 0x27124000 + 7059143

4       UIKit                                   0x274b60c5 0x27124000 + 3743941

5       UIKit                                   0x2740fc65 0x27124000 + 3062885

6       UIKit                                   0x27130b57 0x27124000 + 52055

7       QuartzCore                              0x26b5bf65 0x26b4f000 + 53093

8       QuartzCore                              0x26b57951 0x26b4f000 + 35153

9       QuartzCore                              0x26b862a5 0x26b4f000 + 225957

10      UIKit                                   0x2741b41b 0x27124000 + 3109915

11      UIKit                                   0x2741d627 0x27124000 + 3118631

12      UIKit                                   0x2721b199 0x27124000 + 1012121

13      UIKit                                   0x2721b0b9 0x27124000 + 1011897

14      UIKit                                   0x276003ab 0x27124000 + 5096363

15      UIKit                                   0x27164795 0x27124000 + 264085

16      UIKit                                   0x2717a3d1 0x27124000 + 353233

17      UIKit                                   0x27600319 0x27124000 + 5096217

18      UIKit                                   0x273bcdd1 0x27124000 + 2723281

19      UIKit                                   0x273bdcc7 0x27124000 + 2727111

20      UIKit                                   0x273be10f 0x27124000 + 2728207

21      UIKit                                   0x271a8a7b 0x27124000 + 543355

22      UIKit                                   0x271a8a17 0x27124000 + 543255

23      UIKit                                   0x271a88e7 0x27124000 + 542951

24      UIKit                                   0x271a8867 0x27124000 + 542823

25      UIKit                                   0x271a0e83 0x27124000 + 511619

26      UIKit                                   0x27134bcd 0x27124000 + 68557

27      UIKit                                   0x27134721 0x27124000 + 67361

28      Foundation                              0x24995dc9 0x248d0000 + 810441

29      CoreFoundation                          0x23c55517 0x23b87000 + 845079

30      CoreFoundation                          0x23c55099 0x23b87000 + 843929

31      CoreFoundation                          0x23c53303 0x23b87000 + 836355

32      CoreFoundation                          0x23ba0981 0x23b87000 + 104833

33      CoreFoundation                          0x23ba0793 0x23b87000 + 104339

34      GraphicsServices                        0x2af5f051 0x2af56000 + 36945

35      UIKit                                   0x27192981 0x27124000 + 452993

36      myTaxiControlmD                         0x000f155b main (main.m:6)

37      libdyld.dylib                           0x31eddaaf 0x31edc000 + 6831
```

Comment: It is impossible to know if we only have these information.

Comment: You need to symbolicate the system calls.